Drag force equation using the pressure distribution in fluid dynamics
I want to obtain the drag force equation for a flow around a cylinder.
Starting with the definition of pressure:
$${\displaystyle d\mathbf {F} _{n}=-p\,d\mathbf {A} =-p\,\mathbf {n} \,dA.}\tag1$$
integrating over the area:
$$F=-\int_A pn_i dA\tag2$$
How do I obtain the following expression:
$$F_D=\int _{S}\mathrm (p-p_{o})\left({\hat {\mathbf {n} }}\cdot {\hat {\mathbf {i} }}\right)rd\vartheta\tag3$$
where $p_0$ is the pressure of the undisturbed flow, $r$ is the radius of the cylinder, $\vartheta$ is the angle in the circular direction of the cylinder, and $\hat {\mathbf {i}}$ is the unit vector in direction of free stream flow.
Particularly I am interested how can I explain the $-p_0$ term that appears under the integral sign.
It is really usefull if we are using the following function for pressure $p(\vartheta)$:
$$p(\vartheta) = p_0 + \frac{\rho V^2}{2}(1-4sin^2(\vartheta))$$
because the $p_0 - p_0$ cancel and we end up with a result that is independant of the pressure of the undisturbed flow, but I don't know how to justify just putting $-p_0$ under the integral sign like that.

This might help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

You already have it for the case of a cylinder:  $rd\theta$
